# Change UIImagePicker Navigation Bar style to blue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

All of my view has a blue navigation bar but when I want user to choose a photo, the UIImagePicker is black. I tried to set the navigation bar of UIImagePickerController to blue using UIBarStyleDefault but it does not work for me, the color is still black. I tried with other UIBarStyle like UIBarStyleBlack and UIBarStyleOpaque as well but it doesn't change the navigation bar of the picker anyway. Here is my code

```
    // Let the user choose a new photo.
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no way to change it. So my solution is using Color Meter to get the color of the default navigation bar in color code: red code, blue code, green code. Then I use the method

imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redCode green:greenCode blue:blueCode alpha:0.1];

[UINavigationBar tintColor](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor)

[UIColor Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)

Comment: @ iOS7 it will change font.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is using

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated {
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
}
```

that is an istance method of the [UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

This will change the navigation bar style to blue.

Answer (score 0):

using the delegate to change it worked for me.