# Is there any way to customize the toolbar in UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When the image picker is presented and a user takes a picture, the photo is displayed on another view. The two toolbar items are "retake" and "use." Is there any way to change "use" to "upload"?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the UIToolBar's [color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972707/change-uiimagepicker-navigation-bar-style-to-blue), but I believe that the "Use" verbiage is unchangeable.  This is part of Apple's API, and in truth you probably don't want to change it.

Think about internationalization.  The default verbiage is localized to whatever the iPhone's location is.  If you change it to "Upload" or something else, then you lose all of that functionality that you otherwise would have gotten "out of the box."  And I don't know about you, but I don't know how to say "Use" in farsi.

Cheers,